# Cannot access new Google Calendars created from the API using a Service account

Tags: google-calendar-api

We are using the Google Calendar API to create calendars and manage them on the behalf of the users.

For this, we create a calendar with an ACL rule like this:

```php
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$client->setAuthConfig('/.../oauth_secret.json');
$client->setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI);
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();
$calendar->setSummary($calendarName);
$calendar->setTimeZone('Europe/Paris');
$newCalendar = $service->calendars->insert($calendar);
$calendarId = $newCalendar->getId();

$rule = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRule();
$scope = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRuleScope();
$scope->setType("user");
$scope->setValue("295093256...012ulkk4oklusjh8...@developer.gserviceaccount.com");
$rule->setScope($scope);
$rule->setRole("owner");
$service->acl->insert($calendarId, $rule);
```

Therefore we attempt to access the calendar like this:

```php
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$client->setAuthConfig('/.../private_key.json');
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();

$this->service = new Google_Service_Calendar(client);

$calendar = $service->calendarList->get($calendarId);
```

Until a few months ago, this was working perfectly, but now we get this error:

```json
google_runner error: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

It still works for calendars created before but not the new ones. I'm requesting help as I cannot find the reason why.

Note the ACL is properly created on the new calendars as you can see here:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Have you shared the calendars with the service account? I guess that the last image in french is showing that but in case you can confirm. 
What do you mean with new ones?
Are you using Domain Wide Delegation?

Comment: Yes, I'm sharing it by setting the email address of the service account (using the API, and it appears on the Google Calendar as the image show). It stops working a few months ago, and calendars created before that are still accessible, it does not find only the new one I create. And yes, I have the checkbox Domain Wide Delegation checked for the service account.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

Google does not automatically create anymore an entry to the user's calendar list when you create a calendar.

To check if the calendar exists, I just needed to replace:

```
$calendar = $service->calendarList->get($calendarId);
```

By

```
$calendar = $service->calendars->get($calendarId);
```